# IBM Watson - Facebook ChatBot

Tags: ibm-watson, facebook-messenger-bot

I am trying to implement IBM Watson chatbot into facebook messenger. I am able to verify my webhook. Also, able to receive and send custom messages through facebook to my webhook locally.

But when another user tries to access my page and then send message from facebook to my chatbot, it fails to respond unlike when i message it locally. I donot understand why it could be failing? Any help/direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have not yet had your messenger bot reviewed and approved by Facebook. Until your bot goes through the review process, it can only be accessed by you.

Answer (score 0):

You can invite other users to test your chatbot, and as @chughts mentions before you can go public Facebook has to approve.